# Plunker is showing the preview of html but not my JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn JavaScript using Plunker.  Plunker is showing the preview of html but not my JavaScript.  Please help.

Comment: Add some code or example. what you have tried? , where you're finding problem

Comment: You may have accidentally closed the HTML panel. If you show the project file tree button and then click the file you're working then you can reopen this window/panel

Answer (score 0):

You can review the console to check it. [Google inspect](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/)

Comment: This should be a comment. Not an answer